# Reference a property in another unrelated View Controller

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift, architecture

I have a question regarding best practices for Cocoa application architecture. If you look at the screenshot of my app's storyboard there is a view controller in the bottom left (which many controls) and there are two view controllers with table views in a split view controller, on the right side. I need to reference array controllers that are in each of the table view controllers (right side ) inside the controls view controller (left side).

How do I reach those array controllers all the way through the view hierarchy (which goes through different container views, etc.)?

I could of course just refer them in my app delegate, which is a singleton, and get them from there but we all know that this is not good OOP architecture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own `Singleton Class` for that. Like `AppNameDataManager` then create properties and set them from the view controller where you have to set and get in view controller where you have to get.

```
#define SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(classname)\
+ (id) sharedManager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;\
    static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });\
    return _sharedObject;
}
```

just import that class and get instance by calling **`[ClassName sharedManager]`**

Comment: But how is this much different from using app delegate as a hub for references? I was wondering if there is instead an OOP good practice way to channel references through some other means than a singleton hub.

Comment: It won't increase the code in your app delegate and keep your code separately for access from anywhere. Even Singleton is a design pattern for iOS so thats not bad to use it. Either you have to send the variable from next to next controller till the target controller.

Comment: Singleton is a design pattern but I think it can easily be misused as a hub for just about anything in the architecture. In a small app it's probably no big deal. I made it like this now: Created a Model class which serves as a 'hub' for all data related in/out but model ref. is kept in app delegate, not much different from your suggestion but works for me.